# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Não indica mensagem de erro

Tags: vb.net, webforms, visual-basic-6, nullpointerexception

O meu sistema(WEBFORMS VB.NET) tem apresentado uma exceção de objeto nula(**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**), que acontece apenas no servidor de produção após um período de tempo indeterminado.

Ou seja:
Após resetar o pool a aplicação volta ao normal, porém após algum tempo a exceção volta. E quando o erro acontece **TODAS** as páginas do projeto ficam inacessíveis, sendo necessário o reset do pool.

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O erro não produz mensagem especificando página ou linha específica
- Já foi verificado e todas as conexões com o DB estão sendo fechadas/abertas corretamente
- O projeto tem uma quantidade considerável de páginas, classes etc.
- O compilador não acusa nenhuma variável ou warning referente a isso

---

Existe alguma forma de conseguir chegar até a raiz do erro?

Comment: tem o código que dá esse problema?

Comment: Então, esse é o ponto chave! Nada foi alterado no projeto. Nem a IDE nem o navegador retornam uma pista de onde está o erro, logo não sei em qual arquivo está o erro